# Check systemd unit with monit

Tags: systemd, monit

I need to check a program that has a systemd unit under user namespace and this is my monit conf (systemd conf works without any problem):

```
check program foo with path "/usr/bin/systemctl --user -q is-active foo" as uid pioz and gid pioz
  start program = "/usr/bin/systemctl --user start foo" as uid pioz and gid pioz
  stop program = "/usr/bin/systemctl --user stop foo" as uid pioz and gid pioz
  if status != 0 then restart
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

This conf does not work because I get the error `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`. I get the same error if I run the follow command `sudo /usr/bin/systemctl --user -q is-active foo`, so seems that the directive `as uid pioz and gid pioz` does not work. If I change the config like this, all works well.

```
check program foo with path "/bin/su -c '/usr/bin/systemctl --user -q is-active foo' pioz"
  start program = "/bin/su -c '/usr/bin/systemctl --user start foo' pioz"
  stop program = "/bin/su -c '/usr/bin/systemctl --user stop foo' pioz"
  if status != 0 then restart
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Any idea why `as uid` does not work?

Comment: have you ever been able to figure it out? @Pioz

Comment: Could you be running into an issue where monit executes programs with very few [environment variables](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#ENVIRONMENT) and so no DBUS info is present whereas using `su` causes an environment to be setup? May be able to debug using [the monit FAQ](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ#execution).